# DevTools failed to load sourcemap System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Making a chrome extension. Using typescript and bundling using webpack. Having trouble with my content.bundle.js not having color highlighting.

[image]

Here is my webpack configuration

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    content: {
        import: './src/content.ts',
    },
    service_worker: {
        import: './src/service-worker.ts' 
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }, 
  devtool: 'source-map', 
  mode: 'development'
};
```

[image]